# Check if an object is null within itself in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object, null

Can I check if an object is null within the object's own .as-file? `if(this != null)` does not work, because it tries to run the code even if the object's parent have nulled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code that's within an object definition is executed, and that code is not static, then `this` is certainly not null. You might check for parent's existence instead, or check for internal flags, or listen to `REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` event to learn that `this` is about to be discarded. IMHO the best way will be checking for parent or stage. If `parent` is not null, then `this` is a part of display list of some object - which might still be discarded because of *its* parent's actions. But if `stage` is not null, then `this` is actively participating in display list of your entire application. So instead of `if (this != null)` you check for `if (this.parent != null)` or `if (this.stage != null)`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time :) I actually svolved my problem doing something completely different, but I think your tip would work too :)

Answer (score 0):

From the definition, `this` is reference to a method's containing object.
See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#this.

So I don't see a way how `this` could return `null`.